# What do I need to change to ensure that I can calculate with the outcome?

Tags: c#

I have a complicated problem, at least in my opinion. I am making a calculator in C#. The basics are working right now. But I want to make it work better.

The problem I have is this: When I do `20+10` I get `30`. This is also correct. But when I want to calculate with this and click on `+5` I don't get `35`, which it should. I know what it is. This includes the variable 'times' and 'result'. In any case, I understand how the computer arrives at the other result. I just don't know how to fix and fix this.

Another example to clarify:
If I do `8+5` I get `13`. If I do `+3` I get `11`.
Does anyone have an idea what I should change in my code? Or do I have to change my entire code?

I have asked this question earlier but I can't figure it out and they said that if I can't I must ask a new one. It seems like they don't know how to change it too.

This is my code (in visual studio with windows forms):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string first;
        string second;
        string userInput = "";
        string space = " ";
        char function;
        int times;
        double result;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void number1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "1";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }
        private void number2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "2";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "3";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "4";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "5";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "6";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "7";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "8";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void number9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "9";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            first = "";
            second = "";
            userInput = "";
            result = 0.0;
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "0";
            feedback.Text = "";
            times = 0;
        }

        private void divideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '/';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "÷";     
        }

        private void multiplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '*';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "*";
        }

        private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '+';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "+";
        }

        private void minusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            function = '-';
            first = userInput;
            userInput = "";
            feedback.Text = first + space + "-";
        }

        private void equalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            times++;
            second = userInput;
            double firstNum, secondNum;
            firstNum = Convert.ToDouble(first);
            secondNum = Convert.ToDouble(second);
            
            if (function =='+')
            {
                result = firstNum + (secondNum * times);
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = (result - secondNum) + space + "+" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
            else if (function == '-')
            {
                result = firstNum - (secondNum * times);
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = (result + secondNum) + space + "-" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
            else if (function == '/')
            {
                if(secondNum == 0)
                {
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = "Error";
                    feedback.Text = firstNum + space + "÷" + space + 0 + space + "=";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = firstNum / Math.Pow(secondNum, times);
                    calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                    feedback.Text = result * secondNum + space + "÷" + space + second + space + "=";
                }
            }
            else if (function == '*')
            {
                result = firstNum * Math.Pow(secondNum, times);
                calculatorDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                feedback.Text = result / secondNum + space + "*" + space + second + space + "=";
            }
        }
        
        private void decimalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text += ".";
        }

        private void zeroButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calculatorDisplay.Text = "";
            userInput += "0";
            calculatorDisplay.Text += userInput;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're dealing with numbers you should use `double.Parse()` at least. there are multiple things wrong with this code.

Comment: You want to add results to "feedback.Text = first + space + "+";"  So you need to use int.Parse(string) to get two numbers and then add and convert back to a string.

Comment: I think you need to somehow keep track of the state of your calculator. As an example, whenever you click the `+` and thereby enter `plusButton_Click( )`, it is relevant for you to know whether you need to continue the calculation (e.g. set the value of `first`) based on the user input (as is the case in your `20+10` scenario) or based on the result calculated in `equalButton_Click( )` (as is the case in the `+5` scenario directly following the `=` click).

Comment: @Astrid, yeah good point. Thanks for your tips guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a history of what the user has entered, then every time they hit a button, evaluate that history. This also gives you the ability to back up (undo) if needed.

Here's an example I threw together. I seems to work ok but could use more error handling. It's a console app but you can use the main code in your forms app

```
public class Program
{
    // Do a simple math operation
    static double calc(string oper, double op1, double op2) {
        if (oper == "+") return op1 + op2;
        if (oper == "-") return op1 - op2;
        if (oper == "*") return op1 * op2;
        if (oper == "/" && op2 != 0) return op1 / op2;
        return 0; // Should throw here
    }

    static List<string> operators = new List<string>(){"+", "-", "*", "/"};

    // Process a list of user input
    public static double eval(List<string> hist)
    {
        double result = Double.Parse(hist[0]);
        double curEntry = 0;
        string op = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < hist.Count; i++) {
            // It's an operator (+,-,*,/)
            // So use current result and next number in list
            if (operators.Contains(hist[i])) {
                op = hist[i];
                if (i < hist.Count - 1 && Double.TryParse(hist[i+1], out curEntry)) {
                    result = calc(op, result, curEntry);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
            // Since we keep a running total, only need to handle =
            // when there are 2 or more in a row
            else if (hist[i] == "=" && i > 0 && hist[i-1] == "=") {
                result = calc(op, result, curEntry);
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Testing - use a list to simulate user actions
        List<string> hist = new List<string>() {"5", "+", "3", "=", "=", "*", "5", "*", "2", "=", "="};
        // Go through as if someone is entering the data
        for (int i = 0; i < hist.Count; i++) {
            List<string> temp = hist.GetRange(0, i+1);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", String.Join(" ", temp), eval(temp));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
5 -> 5
5 + -> 5
5 + 3 -> 8
5 + 3 = -> 8
5 + 3 = = -> 11
5 + 3 = = * -> 11
5 + 3 = = * 5 -> 55
5 + 3 = = * 5 * -> 55
5 + 3 = = * 5 * 2 -> 110
5 + 3 = = * 5 * 2 = -> 110
5 + 3 = = * 5 * 2 = = -> 220
```

---

Update: In answer to your comment asking how to use this in a Winforms app. First, create a UI like this:
[image]

(The textbox is named "result".)

Then add a single button handler for all buttons:

```
List<string> history = new List<string>();
private void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number;
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (Int32.TryParse(btn.Text, out number)) // It's a number button?
    {
        result.Text += btn.Text;
    }
    else if (btn.Text == "CLEAR")
    {
        history.Clear();
        result.Text = "";
    }
    else if (btn.Text == "=")
    {
        if (history[history.Count-1] != "=") history.Add(result.Text);
        history.Add("=");
        result.Text = eval(history).ToString();
    }
    else  // It's an operator (+,-,*,/)
    {
        history.Add(result.Text);
        history.Add(btn.Text);
        result.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it and see if it works in windows forms too.

Comment: When I test your code online, there is 1 problem. It says the type or namespace 'List' could not be found

Comment: You need to add `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Yeah that's it thanks. I will look how I can use this for my calculator

Comment: But how can I use this code with buttons in my calculator?

Comment: @HenkAap Updated with an example.

Comment: It's a late reply from me, but thank you very much Johnny!

Comment: Is the name of the button 'btn'?

Comment: `btn` is the name of the variable of button that is passed to the function: `Button btn = sender as Button;`

Comment: Thanks! I will try it today and look if I have any problems

Comment: There is an error with 'eval(history)'. The name eval does not exist in the current content. And I don't know what the reference of the button handler is. I'm sorry i'm quite new to c#